# Bootstrap - fill remaining vertical space

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to design this layout using bootstrap. I put logo and navbar but now I have to insert the remaining div.
I need to extend this div (with the question mark) to the remaining space of the page (with margin like the picture).
I don't know logo or navbar percentage height.

[image]

---

**Edit:** Post my code (source page of Yii Framework)

```
 <a href="index.html"><img width="150" src="images/logo.png"/></a>
 <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
 <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button class="navbar-toggle btn btn-default" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#yii_booster_collapse_yw0" id="yw1" name="yt0" type="button">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button></div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="yii_booster_collapse_yw0">
            <ul id="yw2" class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active">
                    <a href="index.php/site/home">Home</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="pull-right nav navbar-nav" id="yw3">
                <li>
                    <a href="index.php/user/profile/edit">Profile</a>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="index.php/site/home">Options <span class="caret"></span>
                    </a>
                    <ul id="yw4" class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li>
                            <a tabindex="-1" href="index.php/site/contact">Contact Us</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a tabindex="-1" href="index.php/user/profile/changepassword">Change password</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
   </div>
 </nav>
 <div id="content">
     fill vertical space
 </div>
```

I need to fill remaining space, not logo/brand problem.

Comment: Post your code if you want an answer.

Comment: You could wrap in divs and set height 100% (there's more to this, this is quick answer), or you could try flexbox, it has something to do this built in that's pretty neat.

Comment: If i use height:100% i have scroll bar, I don't want this (if content doesn't need)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You will see in the css that I used **calc()** in the `height`value to do a subtraction.

First get the viewport height of the device screen size by using `100vh` then subtract the height that is used above the div that you want to fill to take up the rest of the screen.

Here is the **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fk431h86/)**.

Does this help?

PS: I commented in your nav code where you have a extra `div`and where I added a `</li>`.

```
.block {
  height: -webkit-calc(100vh - 72px);
  height: -moz-calc(100vh - 72px);
  height: calc(100vh - 72px);
  background-color: rgba(90,90,190,0.8);
}
```

Comment: What if you don't know the height of the top element (i.e. it's dynamically calculated based on its contents)?

Comment: Hi there, You might need to try using some JS code to dynamically calculate that and feed that into the calculation.